# Перевод кодировки Windows-1251 в Koi8-R

Tags: delphi, кодировка, delphi-7

Прошу подсказать, либо направить: как переводить строки кодировки Windows-1251 в Koi8-R

Comment: http://forum.ixbt.com/topic.cgi?id=40:1066

Comment: @Yura Ivanov Спасибо!)

Answer (score 1):

Например с помощью таблиц соответствия символов:

http://forum.ixbt.com/topic.cgi?id=40:1066

```
function Convert(const s: string): string;
const
  ReplacementTable: array[#128..#255] of Char = (..,..,..);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  Result := s;

  for i := 1 to Length(s) do
    if s[i] > #127 then
      Result[i] := ReplacementTable[s[i]];
end;
```